# Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of Airys; DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have following ODE

$$ -y'' + xy = - \lambda y $$

$$ x \in (0,1), \; \;\;\; y(0)=y(1)=0$$

I proved using integration by parts that the eigenvalues are positive. Is there a way to compute or plot the eigenvalues in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the form of shifted Airy functions

$$ y(x) = c_1\operatorname{Ai}(x+\lambda) + c_2\operatorname{Bi}(x+\lambda) $$

The two boundary conditions give

\begin{array}{lll} 
c_1\operatorname{Ai}(\lambda) &{}+ c_2\operatorname{Bi}(\lambda) &= 0 \\
c_1\operatorname{Ai}(1+\lambda) &{}+ c_2\operatorname{Bi}(1+\lambda) &= 0
\end{array}

which has a non-trivial solution if

$$ \operatorname{Ai}(\lambda)\operatorname{Bi}(1+\lambda) - \operatorname{Bi}(\lambda)\operatorname{Ai}(1+\lambda) = 0 $$

You can solve this equation using numerical methods.